# Почему не пускает в свой же канал?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Пытаюсь пригласить человека в канал через библиотеку telethon
Канал мой, публичный
Выдает такую вот ошибку:

```
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChannelPrivateError: The channel specified is private and you lack permission to access it. Another reason may be that you were banned from it (caused by InviteToChannelRequest)
```

При чем человек у меня в контактах и я могу добавить его вручную через приложение тг

Как исправить не понимаю, перелазил уже все, что только можно - документации оцень мало, вся разрозненная...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

У меня подобная ошибка.
ChannelPrivateError: The channel specified is private and you lack permission to access it. Another reason may be that you were banned from it (caused by SetDiscussionGroupRequest)

Только при попытке присоединить публичную группу к публичному каналу.

Решено. Весь вопрос стоит в том как обращаться к объекту канала, если пихать его юзернэйм, тогда он брекается полагая что такой способ не подходит для управления функционалом, выполнение которого подразумевает админский доступ. Таким образом нужно оборачивать ид и хеш канала в InputPeerChannel(channel_id=newChannelID, access_hash=newChannelAccessHash), а этот объект сувать в исполнительную функцию